# Loop to keep asking for the value until user enters unique value

Tags: bash, lvm

I am creating a script for automated tasks regarding LVM. In the script, I want user to input the VG name and it has to be unique. How to create a loop so that if user enters a VG name that already exists in the system it doesn't move ahead and keeps asking for the VGname until its unique.

The function I am using for VG creation is mentioned below:

```
vg_create(){
        printf "\n"
        printf "The list of volume groups in the system are: \n"
        vgs | tail -n+2 | awk '{print $1}'

        printf "\nThe list of Physical Volumes available in the OS are as follows: \n"
        view_pvs  ## Calling another function
        printf "\n"
        printf "[USAGE]: vgcreate vgname pvname\n"
        read -p "Enter the name of the volume group to be created: " vgname
        printf "\n"

        vg_match=`pvs | tail -n+2 | awk '{print $2}' | grep -cw $vgname`

                if [ $vg_match -eq 1 ]; then
                   echo -e "${vgname} already exists. Kindly enter new name.\n"
                else
                   echo -e "${vgname} doesn't exist in system and will be created.\n"
                fi
        read -p "Enter the name of the physical volume on which volume group to be created: " pv2_name
        printf "\n"
        vgcreate ${vgname} ${pv2_name}

        printf "\n"
        printf "The new list of volume groups in the system are: \n"
        vgs | tail -n+2 | awk '{print $1}'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In general:

```
# loop until we get correct input from user
while true; do
    # get input from user

    # check input

    # break if ok
done
```

Or, a bit more fleshed out:

```
# loop until we get correct input from user
while true; do
    read -r -p "Give your input: " answer

    # check $answer, break out of loop if ok, otherwise try again

    if pvs | awk 'NR > 2 {print $2}' | grep -qw -e "$answer"; then
        printf '%s already exists\n' "$answer" >&2
    else
        break
    fi
done
```

Note: I have no idea what `pvs` does.

Comment: pvs displays all the Phyical Volumes available in OS.

Answer (score 1):

Here's two different ways to check for the existence of a VG:

1. attempt to read the VG directly `vgs --readonly "$vgname"`; if that command succeeds, the VG already exists.
2. If the vgname is listed in the output from `vgs`, the VG already exists.

Note that the second method specifically asks `vgs` to *not* print the heading and to only print the VG name field. The name is (on my system) often printed with leading and trailing spaces, which is why the `grep` expression looks the way it does.

```
read -p "Enter the name of the volume group to be created: " vgname
while vgs --readonly "$vgname" > /dev/null 2>&1
do
  read -p "Enter the name of the volume group to be created: " vgname
  if vgs --noheadings -o vg_name | grep -q "^ *${vgname} *\$"
  then
    printf "That VG name is already taken; try something else\n" >&2
  fi
done
```